# Table size appears to be larger, but when I download the database, the table size appears to be smaller, what is the reason behind this?

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I check in the database, the table size appears to be larger, but when I download the database, the table size appears to be smaller, what is the reason behind this?

For example, It shows 2688672KB OR 2.6GB on the MySQL server, but when I download the file, it shows 1.24 GB. Why is there so much variation?

**1. Query from database**

[image]

**2. File size check from local disk**

[image]

(from Comment)

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM defaultdb LIKE 'dbt_roi'\G 
*************************** 1. row *************************** 
Name: dbt_roi 
Engine: InnoDB 
Version: 10 
Row_format: Dynamic 
Rows: 13595095 
Avg_row_length: 93 
Data_length: 1269825536 
Max_data_length: 0 
Index_length: 1483374592 
Data_free: 7340032 
Auto_increment: 13650025 
Create_time: 2021-06-07 08:58:14 
Update_time: 2021-10-26 00:18:24 
Check_time: NULL Collation: latin1_swedish_ci 
Checksum: NULL
```

Comment: check the size of the indexes.  I don't think those are downloaded (depending on how you downloaded the file):  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and the value of `innodb_file_per_table`.

Comment: @RickJames
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM defaultdb LIKE 'dbt_roi'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: dbt_roi
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 13595095
 Avg_row_length: 93
    Data_length: 1269825536
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 1483374592
      Data_free: 7340032
 Auto_increment: 13650025
    Create_time: 2021-06-07 08:58:14
    Update_time: 2021-10-26 00:18:24
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL

Comment: @tareq , post the additional information [as an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30177460) instead of posting in comment.

Comment: Was the "download" the result of mysqldump?  Or a .ibd file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Data_length:  1269825536 (1.18GiB)
Index_length: 1483374592 
Data_free:       7340032

Total:        2760540160 (2.57GiB)
```

Does this help to illustrate it?

The physical size of the file includes both data and indexes (and unused space, but this is usually small).

When you dump a table, the content of indexes don't need to be included. If you re-import the dump, indexes will be rebuilt from the data. All the dump needs is the definitions of which columns comprise each index.

Comment: So, How can I clear unused spaces? @Bill Karwin

Comment: New data you insert will occupy the free space if possible before the tablespace file is expanded. But since MySQL expands the file in 4MB increments by default, it's normal to have a little bit of free space. I wouldn't worry about it unless it gets very large. If that happens, run `OPTIMIZE TABLE <name>` and MySQL will defragment the table as it copyies data to a new file.

Comment: Yes, I tried with that. And It was a little bit heplfull. `OPTIMIZE TABLE <name>`